# Find $P(796.2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{16}(X_i-50)^2 \leq 2630)$ with a sample of $n=16$ and $X \sim N(50,100)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $X_1,X_2, ..., X_{16}$ is a random sample of size $n=16$ from the Normal Distribution $N(50,100)$, determine:

$$P(796.2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{16}(X_i-50)^2 \leq 2630)$$

Okay well I know that $\overline X \sim N(50, \frac{100}{16})$ and I think that the summation in this is the sample variance so $\frac{\sigma^2}{16}$?

Is that correct? I know how to work with the Normal Distribution and Z tables but I'm confused with this setup because we do not have an X value any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by transforming $X_i-50$ to $N(0,1)$. Then what distribution is the sum of the squares of standard normal distributions?

Comment: That's 'sum of squares of independent STANDARD normal distributions'. In your notation, apparently $\sigma^2 = 100.$ The numbers 796.2 and 2630 in this problem are carefully chosen so that you can use printed tables. (General problems of this type would require software.)

Comment: Fixed the "standard" part

Comment: My comment was not intended so much as a correction, as just an attempt to give a slight extra clue. I gave your nice brief an answer +1 because it should give the kind of help needed without giving an answer that can be printed off and submitted. (But don't be surprised if someone is unable to resist giving such an answer.)

Comment: I got it now. You divide through by $\sigma^2$ and then it follows chi-squared n

Comment: I'm not submitting this question. It's just an exercise I need to do to prepare for my test